# (Processing) Converting type file into type string?

Tags: java, processing, mp3

I'm trying to get my application to open an audio file via a button (which works) and display the data of the file in the console (which also works)

The application is unable to play the file because the function needs a type `String` and the audio file I'm using is of type `File`. How do you convert a `File` into a `String` in Processing?

```
void setup() {  
  selectFile();
  size(300, 300);
}

void selectFile() {
  selectInput("Select a file to process:", "fileSelected");
}

void songTag(File selection) {
    File file = new File(selection.getPath());
  song = minim.loadFile(filepath);
  song.play();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any code here that attempts to _play_ the file.

Comment: @JimGarrison my apologies I have added the code now

Comment: Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask].  Then update your question with the complete stack trace (format as code) and show which line throws the exception.

Comment: try converting the file path into a string and passing it to the function. in java, you can normally do String path = file.toURI().toString(); ... (not sure if this works in processing tho, worth trying anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) to understand Java classes and functions.

The `File` class has several useful functions. You probably want the `getAbsolutePath()` function.

I'm not sure which line of code is showing the compiler error, but you might try something like this:

```
Mp3File mp3file = new Mp3File(selection.getAbsolutePath());
song = minim.loadFile(selection.getAsbolutePath());
```

Also note that the code you posted has other errors: the `filepath` function is never defined, for example. In the future, please try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually shows exactly what you're trying to do.